# How to handle an expected exception in base postgres

Tags: postgresql, testing, except, unit-test

I want to be able to write a `.sql` script that will carry out an action which fails, and the script should only report failure if the action *doesn't* fail.

For example, given initial table:

```
create table tbl(x integer, y integer);
```

I might update this table in a migration with the following:

```
alter table tbl add constraint unique_tst unique (x, y);
```

And want to write a test script for that migration, which will be similar to the following:

```
insert into tbl(x, y) values 
(1, 1),
(1, 1)
;
```

This will fail - which is expected given the constraint - but I'm not sure how to handle that failure in postgres.

Something such as:

```
if does not fail: 
    insert into tbl(x, y) values 
    (1, 1),
    (1, 1)
    ; 
return:
    failure
```

But I have no idea if this exists.

Note - I cannot install any extensions for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl (x, y)
   VALUES (1, 1), (1, 1);

   RAISE EXCEPTION 'test failed, since INSERT succeeded';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN unique_violation THEN
      /* this is OK */
      NULL;
END;$$;
```